# Get Linux kernel module ko file name within running module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Is there a simple way to, within a running Linux kernel module, to determine the full file name for the `.ko` file (ie: `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/mymodule.ko`) associated with the module, **without traversing procfs**, but instead, just relying on internal structures/lists available in kernel space code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

First: your module may have been compiled into the kernel, and thus won't have a file path.

Second: Loading kernel modules from files takes place in userspace. The kernel is passed a module as a data buffer, using the `init_module` system call -- it's theoretically possible that this data was never loaded from a file at all. (For instance, one can imagine a module loader that loads modules from the network, or from a compressed archive.)

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** obtain path to the module file **within the kernel**: the kernel doesn't store it. Moreover, the kernel even doesn't know that path.

There are two syscalls for load a kernel module: `init_module` and `finit_module` (both are defined in `kernel/module.c`). The first one accepts pointer to user space area, where module image resides (user space should read module file into that area before). The second one accepts descriptor to the module's file, but this descriptor is used only for read content of the file, and isn't stored.